# Buttons created using appendChild stacking next to each other

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm **very new** to JavaScript and I've come across an issue.

I've created a to do list and I want to be able to delete list items with a button that I've created using `appendChild()`. There is an input bar where the user can add to the list, but the corresponding "delete" buttons stack next to each other on the first item created instead of next to the item itself. Here is the code:

```js
function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  dltButton();
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();

  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();

  }
}

function listLength() {
  return listItems.length;
}

function dltButton() {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete!"));
  listItems[i].appendChild(btn);

}

for (var i = 0; i < listLength(); i++) {
  dltButton();
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li>Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
<!--
    commented out since this file is not present on SO's network
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  -->
```

The image is here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/grpw3.jpg

StackOverflow won't let me post the image until I have 10 posts.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS. It is difficult to create your problem without more insight.

Comment: Your code gives this error: "ReferenceError: listItems is not defined".

Comment: Do you have CSS? It almost feels like you haven’t applied styling. Maybe `margin-left` to your `<li>` or even a position.